# Sql server pivot solution

Tags: sql-server

I have created a table containing book details as follows

[image]

Now I want to perform operation on the above table such that I should receive result as below

[image]

where Qty in above table is total number Of (Book Sl No) for which all the the fields (Book Manufacturer, Book Model,Vendor, Dispatch Date and Lot) are same

I have tried simple "pivot" and "group by" in Sql Server but the above one is a bit complex for me. So could anyone please help me out with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some of the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you **don't** need `Pivot or any complex query`. A simple `Group by` with `count` should do the job

```
SELECT [book manufacturer],
       [Book Model],
       Vendor,
       [Dispatch Date],
       lot,
       Count(1) Qty
FROM   tablename
where [Dispatch date] >= 16/4/2014
GROUP  BY [book manufacturer],
          [Book Model],
          Vendor,
          [Dispatch Date],
          lot
```

Comment: Thanks that did job great, but what if I want to extract data in terms of date i.e Dispatch date >= 16/4/2014

Comment: @user2470766 Add `...From tablename where Dispatch date >= 16/4/2014 Group by ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select BookManufacturer , BookModel , Vendor , DispatchDate , Lot , Count(*) as Qty
from Books
group by (BookManufacturer , BookModel , Vendor , DispatchDate , Lot)
```